# Facebook notification checkbox disabled

Tags: email, notifications, facebook

I don't want keep getting email from Facebook's updates. So I go to notification setting in my Facebook account, but this is what I get

[image]

So I get **all** the check boxes and the **save change** button **disabled**

What should I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is the *email frequency* checkbox to check or uncheck. It's under **Down-arrow in the upper-right corner** → **Account Settings** → **Notifications**. You can check it if you want emails sent to you about being tagged in a photo, payment confirmation, security or privacy information.

**Uncheck the Email Frequency checkbox then try again, the checboxes will be enabled.**